# Android Checkbox, BYTE value to Int from ENUM

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, enums

I am trying to get specific values from a checkbox dialog i have made with 4 options. So the four values represent bits, if the last option was checked and the rest unchecked it would result in 0001, if the first and last were selected it would give 1001.

I am having trouble actually getting the int value to represent BYTE value this is what i have so far

```
public enum Material
{
    FOLDABLE (1),
    OVERMAXKG (2),
    STORABLE (4),
    AVAILABLE (8);

    private byte val;


Material(int v)
{
    this.val = (byte) v;
}

public byte getValue()
{
    return val;
}
```

Material object class method for changing properties:

```
private byte materialProp;
public void adjustProperties(Matieral mat)
{
    materialProp = (byte) (materialProp ^ mat.getValue());
}
```

This is the alert dialog

```
AlertDialog matDialog;
    final CharSequence[] properties = {
             " Foldable ", " Exceeds 20KG ", " Storable ", " In Stock "};
    final ArrayList propList = new ArrayList();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Material Properties");
```

How would i represent these values into BYTE format, that i can get the int value of??   So if i selected the checkboxes "Exceeds 20KG" then hit OK button it would represent 1001, which would then give me the BYTE value "0100"

Comment: Start with showing your ok button code where you inspect which ones are checked.

Comment: `"Exceeds 20KG" then hit OK button it would represent 1001, which would then give me the BYTE value "0100"`. Typo? It would represent 0100 and the byte value would also be 0100. Why would you have a byte value that would be different from what it represents?